# Is concurrent access to objects in Java a potential source of problems?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have some questions about variables (like `int, long, etc.`) and objects (like `MyClass class = new MyClass()`) when they are concurrently used.

1. If multiple threads were concurrently reading the same object or variable, will there be a problem?
2. if multiple threads were concurrently changing value of the same object or variable, will there be a problem?
3. If at the same time, in a thread I was reading value of an object or variable and in the other thread I was changing the value of that object or variable, will there be a problem?

If there will be a problem, what I should do to resolve it?

Comment: The answer to all of these questions is "it depends", especially upon what you mean by "a problem". Writing correct concurrent code is hard, and subtle and seemingly innocuous changes can easily break it. Without seeing the specific code you are asking about, it is impossible to give a definitive answer.

Comment: Hi Hadi, this is really a bit too broad. Yes, threads concurrently changing objects *is* a problem. That has nothing to do with Java, though, but with the fact that ... well, two things are trying to define the state of an object and are competing. So, that's a *logical* problem. Then: There's books (a lot) on concurrent programming in Java. maybe read one.

Comment: Buy yourself a copy of "Concurrent programming in Java". This is a huge subject.

Comment: 1: Yes, because values can be cached, so you may be using a stale value. 2: Yes, because of stale values. There is also the problem with types that larger than 32 bit (i.e. `long` and `double`), since they may not be atomically updated. 3: What do you mean by "problem"? There can be a problem iff. the type is lager than 32 bit (see 2). There is also the problem that you do not know whether you read the value before or after it was updated.

Comment: @Turing85 I would say "maybe" rather than "yes": it is not a given that there will be a problem, if constructed correctly.

Comment: @AndyTurner I operated under the assumption that no further precautions (i.e. volatile values, locking, atomic objects,...) were used. It should be obvious that it can be done correctly in Java since Java is Turing-complete.

Comment: i'm new in programming. I did not know that there are books available for the concurrency section. thank you friends. I'll read one of them.

Comment: @Hadi if you are new to programming, I suggest you concentrate on more basic topics than concurrency. As I stated, writing correct concurrent code is *hard* - especially if you don't know how to write good single-threaded code first.